# what is @EnableWebMvc in Spring

Tags: spring

Ive been working with spring for a few weeks, been doing some basic web apps, and shortly started to read a bit more deeply about Spring. Specifically i started reading Spring in Action, and im seeing some weird stuff. For example they are using @EnableWebMvc, ive never had to do that, Mvc has always just been set up. They are also configuring some stuff like a view resolver ext,ext. Is this just old code ? Am i reading an older version or edition of the book, or is there something useful in the configurations and changes they are doing?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `@SpringBootApplication` and have the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency on the classpath, you don't have to add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.